# Micronaut / Gradle / Kotlin cannot find a dll file

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, dll, dllimport

My Kotlin Micronaut project imports a jar which itself depends on some DLLs. I have a folder `lib` which contains the jar I'm importing along with the dependent DLLs.

However, when I build my project I get the following error:

```
C:\path\project\lib\stuff.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

I'm importing the jar and DLLs like so:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(files("lib/thing.jar"))
}

...

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs("lib")
    }
}
```

Along with setting the following as a VM option in intelliJ:

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\path\project\lib
```

Curiously, I can execute the contents of the jar itself (it has a class which prints the library version) by `cd`ing into `lib` and executing the following:

```
PS C:\path\project\lib> java -cp thing.jar SdkInfo
  Version: 1.2.3.4
  Licence: Evaluation
  Debug: False
```

Does anyone have any idea why I can run the above and it works but when I build my project it doesn't? I assume this is something related to not having the right paths set.

Thanks in advance!